# Rename or reuse external type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have forked a repository that has it's type definitions in a `@types` repo, which I don't want to fork nor edit.

I changed the fork name and re-published it, but my main application complains that there are no types for `new-repo`. How can I reuse the same typings in `old-repo` from `@types/old-repo` into my `new-repo`?